# create a custom rss feed for website

Tags: jquery, css, rss

I'm trying to incorporate my rss feed into my website but I want to be able to style it and use jQuery to animate it etc

I've had a look around and it seems that the best option is to use [slidedeck](http://www.slidedeck.com/) but it's $99 for a single website which seems like a crazy amount just to be able to do what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to import rss feeds and style them like the ones on slidedeck using CSS and jQuery?

My rss feed is located externally on the wordpress website so i'd need to reference it like this `wordpressname.wordpress.com/feed`

Thanks

Comment: Is this possible - YES, is it a simple answer to give on stackoverflow - No. Some serious developer time has gone into slidedeck, which is why they charge. You can achieve something very similar with CSS and jQuery. But i don't think you'll get all that in one answer here

Comment: @Alex Thomas - Thanks I think I will probably end up doing it using SlideDeck i'm not sure I will get anything quite how I want it unless I do some serious coding

Comment: good luck mate, hope you get the result you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of [tutorials](http://visualrinse.com/2008/09/24/how-to-build-a-simple-rss-reader-with-jquery/) on [jQuery RSS readers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rss+reader+jquery); once you've implemented one, styling to look like the slidedeck version shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks - i've had a look at these but it seems that php is needed as well and i'm a .Net person